# My own Collision detection

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So basically im building my own kinda of collision detection, but i cant quite get the maths correct.

So the way i am doing it is i have a static player and platforms are randomly generated and move towards the player.

This is my code so far:

```
//Checks to see is a platform has been created
if(IsPlatform == true){

        // performs check on the players position && platform position
        if (Player.position.y > 100 && platform.position.x < platform.contentSize.width - Player.position.x/2) {

        // allows you to jump on the platform
            JumpUp = true;

        }else if(Player.position.y < 100 && platform.position.x < platform.contentSize.width - Player.position.x/2){

            // Hit platform
            JumpUp = false;

        }else{

            JumpUp = false;
}
```

But the problem i am having is getting the platform start side to hit the player, as each platform is a different size between 100-400px sometimes the hit is just before the platform start and other times is after (and if im lucky in the correct place).

I have tried many different options but maybe my mind has become blurred so wondring if anyone could help me.

Thanks
Eli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what this code is supposed to do but this check doesn't make any sense:

```
platform.position.x < platform.contentSize.width - Player.position.x/2
```

You shouldn't have platform.contentSize.width in these checks, or if you do it should be to check the center of the platform and it would be written in another way then. Maybe you actually want to write this:

```
 platform.position.x < Player.position.x/2
```